# How to instruct wkhtmltopdf choose high resolution image files in html

Tags: pdf, html, wkhtmltopdf

I try to convert a webpage into pdf.

```
wkhtmltopdf http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/Dr.Dobbs/books/book9/mf1201.htm my.pdf
```

The problem is that the created pdf has very small images, where the image files are quoted in the html file as, for example,

```
<P ALIGN="Center">
<a href="images/fig1_5.gif">
<img src="images/fig1_5t.gif">
</A>
</P>

<P ALIGN="Center">
<B>Fig. 1.5.</B> A coloring of the graph of Fig. 1.2.
</P>
```

Can I instruct `wkhtmltopdf` to use the high resolution `images/fig1_5.gif` rather than the low resolution `images/fig1_5t.gif` in the pdf file? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to use [`cutycapt`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/web/cutycapt) instead.

> [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) is a small cross-platform command-line utility to
>   capture WebKit's rendering of a web page into a variety of vector and
>   bitmap formats, including SVG, PDF, PS, PNG, JPEG, TIFF, GIF, and BMP

```
sudo apt-get install cutycapt
```

To save a html as PDF

```
cutycapt --url=http://whatever/ --out=output.pdf
```

Comment: why use it instead of wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: better and  faster in rendering, I've used it 3 years ago and never faced any problem

Comment: Give it a try, it deserves

Comment: can it create pdf outlines/bookmarks from html headings?

Comment: I don't know yet, I don't need this for me but I'm gonna search if it is

Comment: @Tim I didn't find such property. Does `wkhtmltopdf` provide that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using *.svg files - they are vector images and print great!  Use the style:size to size it appropriately.

```
<div class="logo"><img src="./Print/images/fig1_5.svg" style="height:75px" /></div>
```

I am using these are they come out great!